# Error while installing Winehq

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, wine, ppa

When I use `sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/`
to add winehq this shows up

```
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Instead of screenshot you can copy error messages and paste in the question body

Comment: i checked it and it didn't work for me so i asked here.

Comment: The errors are not what you are trying to add, but what you already have added.  You probably need to go to your Menu -> Settings -> Software & Updates -> Other Software tab and disable the ones containing the `ubuntu-wine` and the `wine-builds` in the name of them that start with the launchpad.  I just added the one that you are trying to add and I don't have any that yours is failing on.

Comment: I just removed all the repositories connected to wine and then again repeated the process it worked.**THANKS**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment above:

The errors are not what you are trying to add, but what you already have added. Go to your *Menu -> Settings -> Software & Updates -> Other Software tab*

[image]

disable the ones containing the `ubuntu-wine` and the `wine-builds` in the name of them.

Rerun your installation steps.